# How do I stop wrapping code when reformat code in phpstorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

If my code reaches the right magin and I reformat code (Ctrl + Alt + L), PHPStorm automatically wrap code. How do I stop this (reformatting code with wrapping)?
I'm working with php and other languages for web development

Comment: what files do you work with? Settings are different for different file types. For example, for HTML files you need to turn 'Wrap text' (Settings/Code Style/HTML/Other) off and set 'Wrap attributes' to 'Do not wrap'

Comment: sorry, I update my question now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See under Preferences > Code Style, where you can tweak by language.

Also check the settings under Preferences > Code Style > General (affects all languages):

[image: PhpStorm > Preferences > Code Style > General]

Comment: I want to keep right margin value fixed at 120, but I think I cannot do that. Thank you!

Comment: This person asked for a way to stop line from wrapping when formatting, this answer tells you how to stop it from wrapping when typing, It will still wrap on format.

Answer (score 10):

I found this worked for me for the auto format wrapping issue:
`Preferences > Editor > Code Style > HTML` 
From there, change the **Wrap Attributes** dropdown select to *Do not wrap* and I also *unchecked* the box **Wrap Text**. See below: 
[image]

*Edit:* I should add that I have the PhpStorm version 2018.2

Answer (score 1):

In newer PhpStorm (and other IntelliJ IDEA based IDEs) versions option is renamed to `Wrap on typing` and moved to `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style`.

[image: PhpStorm screenshot]

Comment: It's not renamed, it's a different function. The original function `wrap when margin is reached` is now permanently enabled. The only workaround is to put a high number into that `Right margin (column)` field.

Comment: Actually, in newer versions, @yb50110 answer above still works